# not clear glass how do I fix is it hacked?

Tags: modeling, rendering, image, transparency, glass

i have a picture in my blender glass how do I fix? Is it hacked?[image]

Comment: It is clear. You can see the world through it. Check out the rendered view (press Z > Rendered)

Answer (score 3):

By default the *Material Preview* mode will use a default HDRI (world image) and that's what is reflected on your object. To change that you can go into the *Viewport Shading* panel and check *Scene World* for example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are a totally beginner to Blender maybe you should watch some [basic tutorials](https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials).

What you see is just a special kind of shading mode which you have chosen here
[image]

Just tap on another button and you see another kind of viewport shading mode.

More information here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html